# Java - not anonymous Comparator analogue to select elements from collection

Tags: java, collections, apache-commons, comparator, java-6

I have an interest problem. There's an abstract class, that will be extended by subclasses.
In the abstract class there's the following method:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass {
    protected List<MyObject> findSpecificObjects(List<MyObject> objectsToSelectFrom, List<MyObject> objectsToCompare) {
        List<MyObject> selected = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
        //there I need to select elements from objectsToSelectFrom
        //using MyComparatorAnalogue with objectsToCompare
        return selected;
    }

    protected class MyComparatorAnalogue implements ??? {
        /*this comparator analogue should have an access to objectsToCompare
        it must select elements from objectsToSelectFrom with property myProperty=someValue, where someValue - value that no one element from objectsToCompare have in the same property myProperty
        */
    }
}
```

Why should I do it such a strange way - because I need to be able to override MyComparator in subclasses. Is there any way to do what I want to? I looked at the Apache Commons Collections, but didn't find anything that could help me in this situation.

For example:

```
objectsToSelectFrom = {[key=Michael,value=23],[key=Luis,value=44],[key=Andrew,value=26]}
objectsToCompare = {[key=John,value=23],[key=Luis,value=44]}
```

Assuming that `myProperty` is the `value` property `MyComparatorAnalogue` should select `[key=Andrew,value=26]` element.

Hope I described it accessibily. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to filter the `List<MyObject>` against a whilelist?

Comment: Yes, something like that. but objects in objectsToSelectFrom and objectToCompare are not the same, they just have (or have not) the same myProperty value.

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 8 and streams, you could do something like this.

```
    List<MyObject> l = new ArrayList<>();
    l.add(new MyObject("foo", "FOO"));
    l.add(new MyObject("bar", "BAR"));
    l.add(new MyObject("baz", "BAZ"));

    List<MyObject> whitelist = new ArrayList<>();
    whitelist.add(new MyObject("other bar", "BAR"));

    Predicate<? super MyObject> inWhitelist = (MyObject o) -> {
        return whitelist.stream().anyMatch((p) ->
          o.getValue().equals(p.getValue()));
    };

    List<MyObject> filtered =
      l.stream().filter(inWhitelist).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now `filtered` contains the `MyObject("bar", "BAR")` which has the same `value` as the `MyObject("other bar", "BAR")`.

Comment: I have to use Java 6 :(

Comment: Java 6 is deprecated.

Comment: Yep, but some parts of project that I'm working at brokes when it runs on Java 7+. Don't ask how and why - I don't know :)